# Using Select Expression and Field Calculator in ONE STEP with QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I have an Open Street Map Shapefile and I want to use Field Calculator to add information to a field called **a800900** according to the field  **TYPE** of street, by different area (field called **ID_2**).

The field TYPE of street has the following values

- motorway
- trunk
- primary
- secondary
- tertiary
- residential

And the field **ID_2** is a numeric code for 85 municipalities:

- 8527
- 8300
- 8302
- ...

[image]

The information added to **a800900** it's based on the **TYPE** of street and will be different per each **ID_2**. So, I've been selecting each ID_2 and then performing calculations with the Field calculator in two steps.

STEP 1: "Select By Expression"

`ID_2 IS '8283'`

STEP 2: "Field Calculator"

`CASE`

`WHEN TYPE IS 'motorway' THEN 2405.396*0.01847`

`WHEN TYPE IS 'trunk' THEN 2305.396*0.0154`

`WHEN TYPE IS 'primary' THEN 1807.226*0.013`

`END`

The following figure show this process:
[image]

Then, i do similar calculations for another **ID_2**, varying the values in Field Calculator:

STEP 1: "Select By Expression"

`ID_2 IS '8302'`

STEP 2: "Field Calculator"

`CASE`

`WHEN TYPE IS 'motorway' THEN 2405.396*0.75`

`WHEN TYPE IS 'trunk' THEN 2305.396*0.34`

`WHEN TYPE IS 'primary' THEN 1807.226*0.47`

`END`

At the end I'll get values in **a800900** different for each **TYPE** of street and **ID_2**. As example, if **ID_2** is 8300 and **TYPE** of street is motorway, then **a800900** is 2450, if **ID_2** is 8302 and **TYPE** of street is motorway, then **a800900** is 2300, and so on.

I have to make the estimation with Field Calculator for each **ID_2**, being 85 areas, and that's why I'm looking for a faster procedure. I would like to know if there is a ONE STEP procedure with Field Calculator, like:

`CASE`

`WHEN ID_2 IS '8283'AND WHEN TYPE IS 'motorway' THEN 2405.396*0.01847`

`WHEN ID_2 IS '8283'AND WHEN TYPE IS 'trunk' THEN 2305.396*0.0154`

`WHEN ID_2 IS '8283'AND WHEN TYPE IS 'primary' THEN 1807.226*0.013`

`WHEN ID_2 IS '8302'AND WHEN TYPE IS 'motorway' THEN 2405.396*0.75`

`WHEN ID_2 IS '8302'AND WHEN TYPE IS 'trunk' THEN 2305.396*0.34`

`WHEN ID_2 IS '8302'AND WHEN TYPE IS 'primary' THEN 1807.226*0.47`

`END`

Is there a way to do this in one step?

Comment: Why don't you select all at once? ID_2 in ('8283','123','456') ...

Comment: I think i wasnt clear. I need to create a new field relating ID_2 and TYPE. ID_2 has 85 areas. TYPE 60.000 streets, belonging to these areas (municipalities). Every ID_2 has different Values. I'm gonna edit my question.

Comment: Please explain the rules of the calculation after the THEN cluase. I cannot see the pattern. If we understand the rules, there should be a way to do this.